# Any tips on collision checking and rendering

Tags: java

I just started to make games (1 month, and already made some ugly but learnful games). Now everything is going well: I can make almost anything I want.

There are 2 things which I keep having trouble with: 1) rendering, my first game had 1 fps but I could boost that up to 20+, though that is still bad. recently i found out about lwjgl, and I think I will use that, it provides good rendering, and also has 3D stuff in it. using lwjgl will fix my 1st problem, I think. If anyone has suggestions for better software please tell me.

My second problem, I haven't found a solution for: Collision checking. I keep having problems with this, it either makes the tick so slow, or just doesn't work, my worlds exits out of `int[][]` wich I can then use to get the blocks, any tips on how to do the collision checking, also some things as, should I use a constant gravity, and jumping using vectors or just "Mario style"?

I hope some of you can give me some good tips.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making 3D games, [Java 3D](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html) used to be quite good.

Comment: At the moment im makeing 2d games, though i want to go 3d soon, so i will defenitly look into java 3D, thanks